# Kivy: Kivy Launcher Crash Android

Tags: android, crash, kivy, launcher

I'm tyring to launch my App on my android using the kivy launcher so I can see what happens to widgets pos/size on a smaller screen.

When I launch, it crashes.

So...  I'm guessing I've done something illegal in my App...which runs fine on Windows desktop.

My code is fairly by the book so I'm looking at:

- paths when loading images
- screen configuration

I was using Windows style paths and figured that's bad.  Then I used abspath+"\rest of path" and got the crash.

Next I used local paths like "my data\sprite" and got the crash.

I'm new to Kivy so I don't know what things are valid while running on a PC vs an Android.

As far as screen configuration, no code is written and kivy runs in Window mode on desktop.

Does anyone know what could possibly cause the Kivy launcher to crash on loading without warning?

Kivy 1.9.0

My code is python...I don't use kv files.

------update-----

Log:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84ACtY-m0OXWTFacm1TZXFHZDA/view?usp=docslist_api

Looks like it's my paths when loading resources.  The error says a path doesn't exist but the path and file do exist.

Is there a certain way to construct resource paths to ensure compatibility on all platforms?

Comment: Follow the instructions for [using adb logcat to debug](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform), and add the error to the question if it isn't enough for you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was path construction.

I imported os and os.path to use abspath and os.sep.

I created a path constructor class that returns a platform specific string.

:-)

Comment: `os.path.join('foo', 'bar')` hopefully returns the same value as your home-brew path constructor, otherwise it might be a solid idea to use the built in method for dealing with paths ;-)